# Struggling with vertical-align: middle for inline (not block!) image alignment

Tags: html, css

Most centering solution are about centering some box in another box. I'm not interested in that. I'm interested in centering many images in a paragraph of text to the line that image is in.

Here's some tests. Any idea why the images and svg are not centering on the lines?

Before you close this as a dupe, please actually try applying the solution you're linking to. I've tried about 45 of them and not one has worked. I'm probably just missing something obvious

```css
div { background: pink; }
p { background: yellow; }
svg { height: 1em; fill: purple; }
img { height: 1em; border-radius: 100%; }
a { text-decoration: none;  }

.s1 {
  line-height: 1;
}
.s1 * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.s2 {
  font-size: 36px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.s3 {
  line-height: 2em;
  font-size: 36px;
}
.s3 p,
.s3 a,
.s3 img,
.s3 svg,
{
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.s4 {
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 2em;
  font-size: 36px;
}
.s4 p,
.s4 a,
.s4 img,
.s4 svg {
  vertical-align: top;
}

.s5 {
  line-height: 1em;
  font-size: 36px;
}
.s5 * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.sm {
  height: 0.5em;
}
.lrg {
  height: 2.5em;
}

.smtx {
  font-size: 0.5em;
}
.lrgtx {
  font-size: 2.0em;
}

.s6 {
  font-size: 36px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 60px;
}
.s6 * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.s7 {
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
}
.s7 * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.s8 {
  font-size: 24px;
}
.s8 * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<pre>this one do nothing</pre>

<div class="s0">
<p><a href="https://github.com/">S0⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">
</a></p>
</div>

<div class="s1">
<p><a href="https://github.com/">S1⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">
</a></p>
</div>

<div class="s2">
<p><a href="https://github.com/">S2⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">
</a></p>
</div>

<div class="s3">
<p><a href="https://github.com/">S3⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">
</a></p>
</div>

<div class="s3">
<p><svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<a href="https://github.com/">S3b⚫️ 
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">
</a></p>
<p style="text-align: right;"><svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<a href="https://github.com/">S3b⚫️ 
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">
</a></p>
</div>


<pre>just a santity check that vertical-align does anything whatsoever.</pre>
<div class="s4">
<p><a href="https://github.com/">S4⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">
</a></p>
</div>

<pre>To hopefully make it clear I want to align images
in a line that reflows, not align a box in a box and
that images can be larger and smaller than the text</pre>

<div class="s5">
<p><a href="https://github.com/">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="sm"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF" class="sm">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="sm"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF" class="sm">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF" class="lrg">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" class="lrg"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">S5⚫️ 
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">
</a></p>
</div>

<div class="s6">
<pre><a href="https://github.com/">S6⚫️ <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">
S6⚫️ <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">
S6⚫️ <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF"></a></pre>
</div>

<div class="s7">
It's a <span class="smtx">small</span> world but a <span class="lrgtx">large</span> universe <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"><circle cx="25" cy="25" r="25"/></svg>
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/FF0000/FFFFFF">
</div>

<pre>even without images i'd like the text to all center vertically</pre>

<div class="s8">
It's a <span class="smtx">small</span> world but a <span class="lrgtx">large</span> universe</div>
```